# Obtain key of dictionary using Object.keys()

Tags: javascript

I am able to use this to retrieve values by putting entering the numeric value of the index like this:

```
Object.keys(myHash)[0]
```

,but if I use a variable to access the contents like below, the result is always undefined. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
Object.keys(myHash)[indexVariable]
```

Here is another example:

```
function compute() {
var hashmap= new Array(); 
hashmap['a']=14;
hashmap['b']=2;
hashmap['c']=3;
hashmap['d']=4;
hashmap['e']=5;
hashmap['f']=6;
hashmap['g']=7;
hashmap['h']=8;
for (var each in hashmap){
    console.log(Object.keys(hashmap)[each]);
}
```

}

Comment: Because `indexVariable` doesn't contain what you think it does?

Comment: `each` is not a numerical value in that example.

Comment: you're right. When you iterate over a hashamp it uses the key value as  "each"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys()` is just an *array* of the key names - you can't use it directly to access the elements of the original object.

Notwithstanding that you should be declaring `hashmap` as an `Object` rather than an `Array`, there's no need to use `Object.keys` unless you actually want the names of the object's own (enumerable) properties.  Your `for ... in` loop will work just as well:

```
for (var each in hashmap) {
    console.log(hashmap[each]);
}
```

The only thing you get extra with using `Object.keys()` is a guarantee that you won't iterate down through keys inherited from the prototype, but you can replicate that too:

```
for (var each in hashmap) {
    if (hashmap.hasOwnProperty(each)) {
        console.log(hashmap[each]);
    }
}
```

Comment: One shouldn't use `for .. in` because it may enumerate prototype properties as well (depending on the platform).

Comment: @nietonfir yes, I've already addressed that.

Answer (score 0):

Your example can't possible work, an array is not supposed to have custom keys. Use an object instead

```
var hashmap = {
    a: 14,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6,
    g: 7,
    h: 8
}
```

[edit] And there's no need to use `for .. in`, use `Object.keys` in conjuntion with `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```
Object.keys(hashmap).forEach(function(i, e) {
    console.log(hashmap[i]);
});
```

Comment: actually an array is perfectly capable of having custom keys - an array is just like any other JS object in this respect.

Comment: FWIW, I think the `.forEach` style loop is overkill in this case - unless you particularly want the extra scope introduced (perhaps to help bind a callback parameter) the `for ... in` loop is more efficient.

Comment: True, although I'm wondering when that happend because I could swear that that wasn't possible two years ago. ;-)

Comment: @niietonfir it has _always_ been possible to add properties to an array, and that's why using `for ... in` is incorrect on arrays - it enumerates both the numerical indices _and_ any properties, including inherited properties.

Comment: @Alnitak One does never stop learning new things. Gotta love StackOverflow! ;-) Although initializing an array with custom key <> value pairs is not possible: `arr = [a: "foo", b: "bar"];` or `arr = new Array(a: "foo", b: "bar");` (That's why I wrongly assumed that custom keys aren't possible in JS arrays).